# Login redirect to native apps in PWA using Cognito

Tags: authentication, amazon-cognito, progressive-web-apps

We use identity providers in Cognito for authorisation of our users (PWA). Cognito redirects users to Facebook web app (browser version) during auth. Can we change such behaviour and lead our users to mobile facebook app on phones?
Note: we use AWS Amplify and connect to Cognito directly from our frontend app.